# Stop refresh after clicking submit form

Tags: javascript, html

Was trying to fill all the form before refreshing !
I mean if the name is wrong i dont want the page to refresh by hitting submit, i want it to wait until i fill all the inputs and they all go right !

I tried return false after every if statement but dosent work i tried e.preventDefault neither works !
Any help ?

```js
            function validateForm(){
                var name = document.loginForm.name.value
                var email = document.loginForm.email.value
                var password = document.loginForm.password.value
                var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    
                if (name.length == 0)
                    return alert("Name wrong");
                else if (re.test(email) == false)
                    return alert('Enter a valid email');
                else if (password.length < 6)
                    return alert('password should be more than 6 characters');
                else 
                    return alert('Form submitted')
            }
```

```html
    <div>
            <form action="" name="loginForm" onsubmit=validateForm()>
    
                <label for="">name</label>
                <input name="name" type="text">
                <label for="">email</label>
                <input name="email" type="email">
                <label for="">password</label>
                <input name="password" type="password">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset">reset</button>
                
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Add required attribute on every input

Comment: Please do some basic searching before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default behavior of submitting a form using the event object.
Inside your `validateForm()` function:

```
 function validateForm(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            ...
        }
```

Make sure you're taking the event object as a parameter inside the function. This will prevent the page from refreshing every time the form is submitted.